# How do we solve this Testing of Hypothesis problem?

Tags: probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

[image]

To find critical region we can use Lemma-Pearson Lemma

$$\frac{L_1}{L_0} > k$$

$$\frac{ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta (1-x)^{\theta-1}}{ 1*(1-x)^{1-1}} > k,\space \space\space \theta >1$$

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta (1-x)^{\theta-1} > k,\space \space \space  \theta >1$$

$$(\theta)^n \prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x)^{\theta-1} > k$$

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x)^{\theta-1} >\frac{k}{\theta^n}$$

Taking log on both side

$$\log_e( \prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x)^{\theta-1} )> \log_e(\frac{k}{\theta^n})$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log_e ((1-x)^{\theta-1}) > \log_e(\frac{k}{\theta^n})$$

Is my approach correct if correct how do we proceed further in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that, given that $H_1$ is a composite hypothesis actually you have to use another method to find UMP test: as an example, monotone likelikood ratio or Karlin Rubin

After some calculations you find that the Statistic Test is

$$T=\sum_i\log(1-X_i)$$

To find the distribution of $T$, first observe that

$$Y=-\log(1-X)\sim \exp(\theta)$$

and thus $\sum_y Y\sim\text{Gamma}[n;\theta]$ that, under $H_0$ it is a $\text{Gamma}[n;1]$

Concluding:

$$-2T\sim\chi_{(2n)}^2$$

Concluding, the rejection region is

$$P(T>k|\theta=1)=\alpha$$

$$P(-2T<k^*|\theta=1)=\alpha$$

or equivalently

$$-\sum_i \log(1-X_i)^2<\chi_{(2n),1-\alpha}^2$$

This is result A